# link static library in c++ visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-linking, dynamic-linking

can someone please help me to understand the process.

in c++ visual studio 2010

i have a  visual studio solution (lets call it mysol)

i have a project built as a static library (let's call it staticprj)
  staticprj needs to use a library from outside (lets call it ext.lib)

in the body of the source code of staticprj i include outside library header file with 
 # include extlib.h and make calls to some of its functions (let call them extfunctions())
 i also include the the path to the header files location of the ext.lib.

the staticprj compiles okay without errors

the mysol also has another project which is a dynamic library (dynprj) and which depends on the staticprj.

also in the source files of the dynprj uses functions from outside library.

i have included #include extlib.h in the source code of dynprj.
 i have included the path of the header files
 i have attached extlib.h directly to the dynprj
 i have also added ext.lib to the linker input (along with the path where the ext.lib resides).

i still get a lnk2001 error stating that extfunctions() where not found.

the whole structure (the mysol solution) compiles okay if i do not use ext.lib at all.

my question is how does the linking process works and what can i do to correct this linking error.

(note that without the presence of ext.lib my linking of the staticprj and dynprj is fine. my compilation works okay and my code works. i only get the linking error when i try to link another ext.lib to staticprj and dynprj and use functions from ext.lib)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure it will work, but try putting the .dll inside your "mysol" debug folder. I had a similar problem couple of weeks ago when I had library compiled as .dll. I just placed that .dll within my debug folder and worked lovely.

Comment: which .dll are you talking about ? do you mean the outside library ext.lib that i am using ? because in the end i am trying to build a dll which uses and outside library ext.lib

Comment: Have you tried : Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input and type in your "libname.lib" and : ...->Conf...->VC++ Directories and add path to your "libname.lib" folder in Library Directories.

Comment: i do it in a different way. i use #progma comment(lib, "libraryname") in the header file. and it works

Comment: Are you sure exfuncs() are within that lib?